# Photoshop bulk "image processor" saved images default to 8bit/channel. Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing

I have an action that, among other things, converts to 16bits/channel. The action works well on an open image.

If I apply the same action through the Image Processor bulk editing, the saved images are all 8bits/channel. The other steps of the action are applied but this one is not.

Or better: even if I apply it to an image that already has 16bits/channel, it goes back to 8. Is there some magic option that interferes?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What image format are you using?  JPG is 8bits per channel. Choose PNG, TIFF or PSD if you want 16bits per channel.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I think that was the issue but my colleague was super duper sure it was possible.